# XML Parsing Error: no root element found (jquery and ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When the code passes through this particular snippet

```
$.post('checkUser.php', {'username':'abc'}, function(data) {

    });
```

I get the following error

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: file:///C:/Users/proj/checkUser.php
Line Number 49, Column 1:
```

This is my checkUser.php (havent much done really)

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'craigslist';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;
session_start(); 

$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db,$port); 

if(!$conn){
  echo "Connection failed";
  exit;
}

exit()
?>
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: this error may come either because of empty response or header of the script. try to put else condition in your checkUser.php and also check the header of the script.

Comment: @MadhurSharma  Sorry, I'm a newbie..but what do you mean by header of the script

Comment: first make sure you did not include any mysql connection file to your checkUser.php file. Header on the script means what type of result you want from the file. either via json, xml or text etc.this you can check via firebug (Content-Type ) as application/xml or application/json etc.

Comment: what is the line of code at line 49 at the **checkUser.php**?

Comment: @gitguddoge 48th line is the last line which is closing php tag (there are some comments made in the actual code)